nuxt + nest + docker
Docker для меня что-то новое,хочу сделать проект в докере и заодно разобраться.
Возник следующий вопрос по ходу прочтения различных статей:
В различных статьях приводятся примеры либо для production, либо development конфигов. А можно ли как-то сделать это все вместе? Например при разработке на локальной машине запускаю что-то вроде npm run dev и проект запускается в dev режиме со всеми горячими перезагрузками и прочее. Когда мне надо задеплоить - копирую на сервер и допустим командой npm run build проект разворачивается в продакшене.
